# Data location on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, automated-deploy

Background: I'm trying to set-up automated deployment with rsync with gitlab runners.

I'm trying to find the actual code stored on a gitlab installation but i don't seem to be able to. I've found the repositories but the data so far is nowhere to be found. Since the repositories should be bare, I haven't really searched the whole repo.

I've tried searching the web, but almost everything only covers the repository locations and not that of the data. A lot also cover moving the data, but only by providing a new storage location which has no original folder, which again, doesn't help me much. I have looked in the default locations, but those folders don't exist.
The only mention of git_data_dir in gitlab.rb is commented, so that's no help as well.

Where should I be able to find the actual code? Or where in the repositories/config files can i find where it is stored?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed gitlab. If you use the omnibus package installation, the actual repositories would normally reside in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories`

If you mean the content that is maintained within the repository: it is not checked out anywhere. A runner checks it out and cleans up afterwards.